# restoring table with pg_restore does not include primary key or indexes

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, database-indexes, pg-dump, pg-restore

So I made a backup of a table using pg_dump:

```
pg_dump -U bob -F c -d commerce -t orders > orders.dump
```

This table had several listed indexes such as a primary key

However when I restore this table into a development database on another system using pg_restore:

```
pg_restore -U bob -d commerce -t orders > orders.dump
```

No primary key or indexes are listed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `> orders.dump` looks wrong for the `pg_restore` command. The input file should be specified as the last argument with the `>`

Comment: I tested, and when you dump a table with `-t tablename`, its constraints and indexes are included in the dump.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing nothing wrong, unfortunately `pg_restore -t` restores only the table, nothing else, regardless of how you created the dump and what is inside the dump itself. 
This has been somehow clarified in [V12 PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgrestore.html), that states:

> This flag does not behave identically to the -t flag of pg_dump. There is not currently any provision for wild-card matching in pg_restore, nor can you include a schema name within its -t. And, while pg_dump's -t flag will also dump subsidiary objects (such as indexes) of the selected table(s), pg_restore's -t flag does not include such subsidiary objects.

the only way to make sure that restoring a table will carry all the indexes is to address them by name, something like:

```
pg_restore -U bob -d commerce -t orders -I index1 -I index2 -I index3 > orders.dump
```

Comment: unfortunately (at least sometimes) there is no option for restoring a constraint, or a sequence, and maybe more, afaics.